# How to test nested props using Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component which has its props value as shown below:

```
emailProps = {email: {isOpen: false}};
```

So, now I am trying to update the value of `isOpen` to true and test if the value of the prop is updated.

```
it('tests after updating isOpen props to true', () => {
    wrapper.setProps({ email:{ isOpen: true} });
});
```

So, I have seen that we can test the prop as :

```
const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent foo={10} />);
expect(wrapper.props().foo).to.equal(10);
```

Since, in my case the prop `isOpen` is inside `email`. So, how do I test it?
I tried it like:

```
expect(wrapper.props().email.isOpen).toBe(true);
```

but it fails.How do I test the nested props?

Comment: Looks ok. You could also use `expect(wrapper.props().email).toEqual({ isOpen: true} )`.  As your solution does not work there must something else going wrong. Maybe start with debugging and log `wrapper.props()` to see what's actual in there

Comment: @AndreasKöberle I tried with `expect(wrapper.props().email).toEqual({isOpen: true});` , but it gives an error saying `Expected value to equal:
      {"isOpen": true}
    Received:
      undefined` .

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with the nested state. I succeeded in this way:

```
it('receives this.state.user.name as a "name" prop', () => {
  expect(header().prop('name')).toEqual(appWrapper.state("user").name);
});
```

In your case, it would look like this:

```
expect(wrapper.prop('email').isOpen).toBe(true);
```